# Requests per second in http.get() - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing a super basic http request app in `node.js`.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'www.domain-here.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    http.get(options, function(res) {
            console.log("[" + this.count + "] Response: " + res.statusCode);
    }.bind({ count: i })).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("[" + this.count + "] Error: " + e.message);
    }.bind({ count: i }));
}
```

I need to get the number of http requests per second though. Any idea how I go about getting requests per second?

Answer (score 3):

```
// begin timestamp
var begin = new Date();

for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    http.get(options, function(res) {
            console.log("[" + this.count + "] Response: " + res.statusCode);
    }.bind({ count: i })).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("[" + this.count + "] Error: " + e.message);
    }.bind({ count: i }));
}

// end timestamp
var end = new Date();

// Then, you need a simple calculation
var reqPerSec = i / ( end - begin );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Date` object to log the time and analyze the numbers afterwards.

Or You could use a `setInterval` in combination with a counter variable if you need real time data.